# Data structures for huge graphs in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, graph, graph-theory

I want to understand how huge graphs can be implemented, so that graph algorithms run faster with huge graphs.

Comment: Get more specific. What kind of graph algorithms? What size are you talking?

Comment: This is an awfully vague question.  I assume you're looking for ways to represent connectivity, but you're likely to have to specify what you mean by "huge" and what sort of graph algorithms you're interested in.  Not all representations work well for all algorithms.

Comment: Are you referring to the boost graph library?  As David stated, please list more details....

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should look at a famous graph library, e.g. [boost graph library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html)

Comment: I don't think this answers the question starting with "I want to understand".

Comment: @doc BGL is well documented and if he wants to understand how they are finally implemented it's no problem to look into the sources.

Comment: if someone asks you on how the car engine works, what are you going to tell him? Take a look at famous car implementation like for example BMW Z3...?

Answer (score 2):

The core idea for graph representation is [incidence matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incidence_matrix). The rest depends on what you need. For example possible solution oriented on quickly finding neighbours are [adjacency matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix).

Comment: Matrices are OK for small and dense graphs, not so sure about their suitability for huge graphs.  Tho' I guess you could use a sparse matrix representation.  Probably easier just to store edges in the first place.

Comment: @High Performance Mark: yes, you can use a sparse matrix or some other sort of compression. That's why I said it depends on what he needs.